# FullCalendar - dayRender appears not working after a 'removeEvents' call

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar v1.6.4 in an ASP.NET MVC application (as a mock).

In one hand, I've implemented the 'dayRender' callback to introduce a "cell.bind('dblclick', function () {...});" (to add an event with a double click on a day cell).

In another hand, I've implemented the 'eventClick' callback to show a KendoUI window pop-up when an event is clicked.

In this window, I've some edition controls & 2 buttons: one to modify the event with the new values from the edition controls and another to delete the event.

The 'delete' button fired the 'removeEvents' callback to delete the current event into the calendar.

All is working well, but when I've processed to the deletion of an event, I then can not add a new event.

The 'dblclick' event appears to be well fired (I've placed some JS alerts to test). And I found no javascript error in my Chrome debugger :s

Does somebody see where I'm wrong please?

Here is my code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Mock";
}

<h2 class="content-title">Mock</h2>

<div class="divSetAddedActivity">
    <input id="ddlMissions" style="width: 250px" />
    <input id="tbxDuration" type="number" value="8" min="1" max="24" step="1" />
    <textarea rows="1" cols="50" id="tbxComment" placeholder="Add a comment"></textarea>
</div>

<div>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
</div>

<div id="window">
    <p id="activityDate"></p>
    <input type="hidden" id="itemId"/>
    <input id="ddlMissions2" style="width: 250px" />
    <input id="tbxDuration2" type="number" min="1" max="24" step="1" />
    <textarea rows="1" cols="50" id="tbxComment2" placeholder="Add a comment"></textarea>
    <button id="btnModifyActivity">Modify</button>
    <button id="btnDeleteActivity">Delete</button>
</div>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        var window = $("#window");

        $("#tbxDuration").kendoNumericTextBox({
            format: "# h",
            decimals: 0
        });
        $("#tbxDuration2").kendoNumericTextBox({
            format: "# h",
            decimals: 0
        });

        if (!window.data("kendoWindow")) {
            window.kendoWindow({
                width: "500px",
                visible: false,
                modal: true,
                title: "Modify activity"
            });
        }

        var today = new Date();
        var d = today.getDate();
        var m = today.getMonth();
        var y = today.getFullYear();

        var userEvents = [];

        var missions = [{ Id: 1, DisplayLabel: 'Mission1' },
                        { Id: 2, DisplayLabel: 'Mission2' },
                        { Id: 3, DisplayLabel: 'Mission3' },
                        { Id: 4, DisplayLabel: 'Mission4' },
                        { Id: 5, DisplayLabel: 'Mission5' },
                        { Id: 6, DisplayLabel: 'Mission6' },
                        { Id: 7, DisplayLabel: 'Mission7' },
                        { Id: 8, DisplayLabel: 'Mission8' }];

        jQuery("#ddlMissions").kendoDropDownList({
            dataSource: missions,
            dataTextField: "DisplayLabel",
            dataValueField: "Id"
        });
        jQuery("#ddlMissions2").kendoDropDownList({
            dataSource: missions,
            dataTextField: "DisplayLabel",
            dataValueField: "Id"
        });

        jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: ''
            },
            editable: true,
            firstDay: 1,
            eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                jQuery("#itemId").val(calEvent.id);
                jQuery("#activityDate").text(calEvent.start);
                jQuery("#ddlMissions2").data("kendoDropDownList").value(calEvent.missionId);
                jQuery("#tbxDuration2").val(calEvent.duration);
                jQuery("#tbxComment2").val(calEvent.comment);

                window.data("kendoWindow").open();
                window.data("kendoWindow").center();
            },
            eventMouseover: function (calEvent, jsEvent) {
                var tooltip = '<div class="tooltipevent" style="width:150px;background:rgb(159,201,175);position:absolute;z-index:10001;"><b>' + calEvent.title + '</b><br/>'+ calEvent.duration + 'h<br/><i>' + calEvent.comment +'</i></div>';
                $("body").append(tooltip);
                $(this).mouseover(function (e) {
                    $(this).css('z-index', 10000);
                    $('.tooltipevent').fadeIn('500');
                    $('.tooltipevent').fadeTo('10', 1.9);
                }).mousemove(function (e) {
                    $('.tooltipevent').css('top', e.pageY + 10);
                    $('.tooltipevent').css('left', e.pageX + 20);
                });
            },

            eventMouseout: function (calEvent, jsEvent) {
                $(this).css('z-index', 8);
                $('.tooltipevent').remove();
            },
            eventRender: function(event, element) { 
                element.find('.fc-event-title').append("<br/>" + event.duration + "h"); 
                element.find('.fc-event-time').hide();
            },
            dayRender: function (date, cell) {
                cell.bind('dblclick', function () {
                    var ddlMissions = $("#ddlMissions").data("kendoDropDownList");
                    var numDuration = $("#tbxDuration").data("kendoNumericTextBox");

                    alert('a');
                    userEvents.push({
                        id: userEvents[userEvents.length - 1].id + 1,
                        title: ddlMissions.text(),
                        missionId: ddlMissions.value(),
                        start: new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate()),
                        allDay: false,
                        duration: numDuration.value(),
                        comment: jQuery("#tbxComment").val(),
                        color: "green"
                    });
                    alert('b');

                    jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                    alert('c');
                });
            },
            events: userEvents
        });

        jQuery("#btnModifyActivity").click(function () {
            var currentId = jQuery("#itemId").val();
            var activity = jQuery.grep(userEvents, function (e) { return e.id == currentId; })[0];
            activity.title = jQuery("#ddlMissions2").data("kendoDropDownList").text();
            activity.missionId = jQuery("#ddlMissions2").data("kendoDropDownList").value();
            activity.duration = jQuery("#tbxDuration2").val();
            activity.comment = jQuery("#tbxComment2").val();

            for (var i = 0; i < userEvents.length; i++) {
                if (userEvents[i].id === activity.id) {
                    userEvents[i] = activity;
                }
            }
            jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
            window.data("kendoWindow").close();
        });

        jQuery("#btnDeleteActivity").click(function () {
            var currentId = jQuery("#itemId").val();
            jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', [currentId]);
            jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
            window.data("kendoWindow").close();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it seems to be solved adding this:

```
jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', userEvents);
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
```

in place of this (at the end of my 'dayRender' callback):

```
jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
```